# retrieve footnote of word file with openxml

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk, office-2010

How can retrieve all footnotes of a word file in c# using open xml, i know that we can retrieve the paragraphs with some things like this:

```
IEnumerable<Paragraph> paragraphs = mainPart.Document.Body.OfType<Paragraph>();
```

but when i test it for footnotes i just get the **null** while i know there is some footnotes in my word file.

i have just find this pages to help me on this problem, but they didn't help me:

[Footnotes constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc803063.aspx)

how can i get all the footnotes and save theme in a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example to get the footnotes:

```
FootnotesPart footnotesPart = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.FootnotesPart;
if (footnotesPart != null)
{
    IEnumerable<Footnote> footnotes = footnotesPart.Footnotes.Elements<Footnote>();
    ...
}
```